# Badge for losing more reputation due to the reputation cap than actually receiving

Tags: feature-request, badge-request, daily-reputation-badges

This happened to me already at least twice: On a good day where I answer a lot of questions I sometimes not only hit the reputation cap but actually loose (i.e. do not receive) a larger amount of reputation because of the reputation cap than I actually receive.

To give an example: 4 accepted answers plus 20 up-votes give 260 reputation, if you then get another 26 up-votes on the same day the additional 260 reputation is lost due to the reputation cap. In my opinion this is a kind of achievement similar to the mortarboard badge and should be honored with an own badge! It could be bronze as well or, taken as the big brother of the mortarboard badge, even silver. I will keep the naming process to the English native speakers.

Comment: So basically you get the badge for earning twice the reputation cap in a single day?

Comment: @Justin: Yes, basically. You could argue about how the cap-free reputation (mostly from answers) is taken into account.

Comment: But it should be a one-time badge, otherwise Jon Skeet will get one every day :-)