# Overachiever badge?

Tags: discussion, badge-request

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Consolation badges for hitting the reputation cap hard](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/119524/consolation-badges-for-hitting-the-reputation-cap-hard)

Possibly silly, but why not have an overachiever badge?

> Overachiever: Received X upvotes, all after hitting the reputation cap

(full disclosure, there's no way I'd qualify for this badge for any non-trivial value for X)

**EDIT**

Or, Andrew's version which I like better

> Overachiever: Received X upvotes on at least Y posts, all after hitting the reputation cap

Which of course would prevent users from getting the badge for one good answer on a popular question.

I'd also be interested in hearing Bronze, Silver, and Gold naming possibilities anyone might have.

---

This was requested [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7060/badge-for-upvotes-after-rep-cap-is-reached), and was oddly marked as status complete with the advent of the Mortarboard, Epic and Legendary badges, even though those badges have nothing to do with votes *over* the cap.

Comment: Sorta related: [consolation-badges-for-hitting-the-reputation-cap-hard](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/119524/consolation-badges-for-hitting-the-reputation-cap-hard)

Comment: Have it apply for X votes, on at least Y posts, after hitting the cap; and be a one-time thing (perhaps with B, S, G variations), and I think I like it.

Comment: @Andrew - yes - absolutely.

Comment: Not only was this suggested before, it was [marked completed with the creation of Mortarboard, Epic and Legendary](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7060/badge). See also [Badge for losing more reputation due to the reputation cap than actually receiving](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/90693/badge), [Badge request: \[2000 rep over cap\]](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/101064/badge) and [Badge suggestion: Overtime](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/38723/badge).

Comment: @PopularDemand - odd that it was marked as complete when Epic and Legendary have nothing to do with upvotes over the cap

Comment: @Andrew: I dislike the Y posts bit. That will just cause people to want to spam additional answers so they can get the badge, if they've already achieved the other requirements.

Comment: @animuson I think I see your point. I guess I was just thinking that it be something beyond, say, having one super-post in a day that gets masses of upvotes.

Comment: This seems like it would almost go hand-in-hand with mortarboard. Yes, some people just hit 200 by the smallest margin and stop, but often enough, people blow right past it. I know it's different, but it's almost like 2 badges for the same thing. (Although we already have something like that phenomenon in another badge pair, Nice Answer and Enlightened.)

Comment: And if it's something given each time it happened, Jon Skeet just got *n* more badges, where n is the number of days SO has existed.

Comment: @Anthony - Nice answer and Enlightened is a good example, and in fact I think this badge would me more dissimilar to epic/mortarboard than enlightened is to nice answer.  But yeah, definitely a one time badge (just like Epic is)

Comment: I would make the badge take into account _only_ additional votes gained on _posts made after_ the daily rep limit was hit.

Answer (score 5):

Given that badges for Mortarboard, Epic and Legendary already exist, this seems a little superfluous.

If this gets enacted, I think having it as a gold only one-time badge makes sense.

Comment: One-time for sure.  I'm not sure how superfluous it is over epic and legendary though.  This badge would be for votes above and beyond the cap.